# Wordpress page edit does not save selected template

Tags: pages, page-template

The feature did work in the past however pages now seem to default to 'Default Template'.

I can see my available page templates in the drop-down on the Page edit page, however after saving the admin simply shows 'Default Template' again.

I have tried disabling all plugins as well as remaking some of the templates, however the behaviour continues.

Any ideas?

Note: I'm using latest self-hosted WordPress.

Update: After some digging it would appear that I am getting 'Table xxx/wp_postmeta' is marked as crashed and should be repaired". However running repair through phpmyadmin does not fix the issue.

Update: Rebuilt the table entirely, still have issue.

(Originally posted this question here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/33627/wordpress-page-edit-does-not-save-selected-template)

Comment: Switch to the default WordPress theme and try adding a custom page template to that theme and test whether or not setting a template under page attributes saves correctly. If so, then its likely something in your functions.php causing the issue (if you say all plugins are disabled).

Comment: Still having the same issue with a default theme.

Comment: [Full troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list?replies=5)?

Comment: Looked through that now, checked a couple of things I had not before. Issue remains.

Comment: Have you tried your theme on a fresh install of wordpress? At least try replacing the wp-admin folder. (Don't forget to backup first.)

Comment: One thing I have not tried is a new WordPress install however I've been holding off on this as I would rather actually fix the problem / learn from doing so.

Comment: Can you please post some of the code which you're using for the page templates? Does it work with the templates that came bundled with the theme?

Comment: @Ing if you are debugging, escape all unneccesary code in your functions file and the faulty template file and get to a working state.then restore your code piece by piece. To create an error like this, can only be your functions file, a faulty plugin or you have editted core files. You cant corrupt an install without changing core files manually or by a badly written plugin. Your solution is probably something real small, just try roll back your code to when it started working and youll find the bug along the way.

Comment: Had the same problem. If I edit the page through "Quick Edit", it saves correctly.

Comment: This looks like it should be a comment rather than an answer in its own right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this was an issue with my hosting.

phpmyadmin although reporting operations as complete was not actually committing repairs / optimisations. Now querying why this is with the company.

So the simple fix was indeed to simply repair + optimise the table.

Answer (score 13):

I had the same issue and it was caused by WPML. I deactivated the option "Synchronize page template" in the WPML translation options and it finally worked.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like your WordPress installation is coruppted. I'd try removing all of the files (except perhaps the `wp-content/` folder and the `wp-config.php` and `.htaccess` files), and then uploading a fresh installation of WordPress.

Create a new MySQL database, if you can, and run the WordPress installer. After installation, you can try importing your blog content back using the **Tools** menu in the WordPress administration dashboard.

It's also a good idea to check for bad code. You've probably already tried reverting to the default theme (Twenty Ten, Twenty Eleven, Twenty Twelve), and disabling all plugins, but you also need to check if there's any files in the `wp-content/mu-plugins` directory, if it exists.

Good luck solving the problem.

Comment: +1 / Thank you for your input, good general troubleshooting tips...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it.

I solved it by going to the table wp_postmeta (through phpMyAdmin) and just edit the record where:

```
post_id = {your post id or page id}
meta_key = _wp_page_template
```

I have changed the `_wp_page_template`'s meta_value to `default`

Hope it works!

Comment: While your solution may work, there is not enough detail here to guide someone through it. Could you edit the answer so that someone with little experience could follow it?

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick note after reading [Björn Weinbrenner's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/249668/107437):

If you're good with all translations having the same template, there's no need to turn off **"Synchronize page template"**.

In this case, the reason the template value is reverting after you save is because you're changing it on a translation of the original page. Just change the template on the same page in the main language and the value will be preserved.

This is the correct procedure, unless you **really** need a different template on a specific language.